# Could not download the upgrades Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04,how to resolve

Tags: upgrade, updates

I am getting this problem  while updating Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04,how to resolve.

```
Could not download the upgrades

The upgrade has aborted. Please check your Internet connection or installation media and try again. All files downloaded so far have been kept.

Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-gsettings_0.4.11-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb Size mismatch
Failed to fetch http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-networkmanager_0.4.11-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb Size mismatch
```

Comment: Can you open the the urls in your browser? If you're behind a filter (say, a company firewall) they might be blocked (maybe due to the word "proxy"?).

Comment: What's the output of `wget -q -S -O /dev/null http://in.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/libp/libproxy/libproxy1-plugin-gsettings_0.4.11-5ubuntu1_amd64.deb`?

Answer (score -1):

I don't think you can upgrade Ubuntu 14.04 to 16.04 through terminal. To do that you need to go to the Ubuntu's official website and go to **Downloads > Ubuntu 16.04.x or 16.04 ** and you should start downloading the file.

Good luck

Comment: You can: `sudo do-release-upgrade`